# jQuery Function Question

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a question concerning functions with jQuery. I have a function that once the browser is ready the function finds a specific table and then adds hover & click functionality to it.

I am trying to call this function from code behind in an asp .net page due to the fact that once someone adds to the database the update panel fires and retrieves a gridview (the table that has been affected by the function at document.ready). When it comes back it is the plain table again.

Here is the original functions:

```
$("#GridView1").find("tr").click(function(e) {
                var row = jQuery(this)
                //var bID = row.children("td:eq(0)").text();
                $('#tbHiddenBatchID').val(row.children("td:eq(0)").text());
                //Took out repetitive code, places values from table into modal




                e.preventDefault();
                $('#modalContentTest').modal({ position: ["25%", "5%"] });
                //row.addClass('highlight');
                //$('#tbEdit').val(bID);
            });

//here is the function that adds hover styling
$("#GridView1").find("tr").click(function() {
            return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
        }).css({ background: "ffffff" }).hover(
            function() { $(this).css({ background: "#C1DAD7" }); },
            function() {
                $(this).css({ background: "#ffffff" });

            });
```

OK, what I tried to do is create a function, call it on document.ready and also in the code behind when after the database has been updated.

Here's what I did:

```
function helpGrid() {
            $("#GridView1").find("tr").click(function(e) {
                var row = jQuery(this)
                //var bID = row.children("td:eq(0)").text();
                $('#tbHiddenBatchID').val(row.children("td:eq(0)").text());
                //
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#modalContentTest').modal({ position: ["25%", "5%"] });
                //row.addClass('highlight');
                //$('#tbEdit').val(bID);
            });

//Haven't even tried to add the hover stlying part yet; can't get this to work.
        }
```

When I try to call helpGrid(); I get an error that's it not defined...

Obviously I'm a jQuery newb but I do have jQuery in Action & I'm scouring it now looking for an answer...

Please help..

Thanks!!!

Comment: corrected the asp.net tag vs a asp and a .net tag...

Comment: thanks...wasn't paying attention...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using an update panel, the entire page does not postback and the document.ready stuff never gets hit...  Below is where you can add a function to run at the end of the update, so resetMyTableStuff(); is where you'll want to do your magic...

Try adding something like this...

```
function pageLoad() {
    if (!Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);
    }
}

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     resetMyTableStuff();
}

function initializeRequest(sender, args) {
      //just in case you need to do it...
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm...interesting, playing with this now. LOL, this is part of the reason I started with jQuery.

Now where is that asp. net Ajax cheatsheet....

Comment: If you were to use the jQuery AJAX stuff, you could simply use the onSuccess function to do the magic, but mixing 3 different things together is a venture on its own.  This is how I've handled it.  I pulled this code right from my app.

Comment: Thanks. I put your code into a separate file and was able to call an alert function with it after sending data from the server. 

I would do the jQuery onSuccess but the button calling the codebehind button in asp .net.

Comment: If you went the jQuery ajax route, you wouldn't be using a button to hit the codebehind, a web service or web method would be called...

Comment: Yeah...thinking of completely going the web service route, but I like how easy it is to let asp do all the heavy lifting with the table. I also have a table that I'm calling with jQuery with a service, ugh...the date that asp sends back through json... /Date(1236097560000-0500)/. that's fun.

Comment: yeah, that is what makes life interesting eh?